# Ionic Json nested

Tags: json, api, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm new in Ionic development. I'm having a problem retrieving JSON.

"Failed to load https://api.wh.geniussports.com/v1/basketball/competitions/19816/matcheslive?ak=eebd8ae256142ac3fd24bd2003d28782: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access."

Here's my json format

```
{
"response": {
    "meta": {
        "version": 1,
        "code": 200,
        "status": "success",
        "request": "http://api.wh.geniussports.com/v1/basketball/competitions/19816/matcheslive?ak=eebd8ae256142ac3fd24bd2003d28782",
        "time": 1528177532,
        "count": 10,
        "limit": 10
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "leagueId": 6,
            "matchId": 784470,
            "competitionId": 19816,
            "venueId": 17386,
            "poolNumber": 0,
            "roundNumber": "1",
            "roundDescription": "",
            "matchNumber": 1,
            "matchStatus": "COMPLETE",
            "matchName": "",
            "phaseName": "",
            "extraPeriodsUsed": 0,
            "matchTime": "2017-11-17 19:30:00",
            "matchTimeUTC": "2017-11-17 11:30:00",
            "enddate": null,
            "timeActual": "2017-11-17 19:45:37",
            "timeEndActual": "2017-11-17 21:12:10",
            "durationActual": 87,
            "temperature": 0,
            "attendance": 0,
            "duration": 120,
            "weather": "",
            "twitterHashtag": "",
            "liveStream": 1,
            "matchType": "REGULAR",
            "keywords": "",
            "ticketURL": "",
            "externalId": "920",
            "nextMatchId": 0,
            "placeIfWon": 0,
            "placeIfLost": 0,
            "updated": "2017-11-24 11:04:00",
            "linkDetail": "/v1/basketball/matches/784470",
            "linkDetailLeague": "/v1/basketball/leagues/6",
            "venue": {
                "venueId": 17386,
                "venueName": "Nanhai Gymnasium",
                "venueNameInternational": "",
                "venueNickname": "Nanhai Gym",
                "venueNicknameInternational": "",
                "surfaceName": "",
                "locationName": "",
                "website": "",
                "ticketURL": "",
                "externalId": "54",
                "linkDetailVenue": "/v1/basketball/venues/17386"
            },
            "leagueName": "ASEAN Basketball League",
            "leagueNameInternational": "",
            "competitionName": "2017 ASEAN Basketball League",
            "competitionNameInternational": "",
            "gsId": "",
            "competitors": [
                {
                    "competitorType": "TEAM",
                    "competitorName": "Singapore Slingers",
                    "competitorId": 88261,
                    "linkDetailCompetitor": "/v1/basketball/teams/88261",
                    "scoreString": "59",
                    "scoreSecondaryString": "",
                    "completionStatus": "COMPLETE",
                    "resultPlacing": 0,
                    "isDrawn": 0,
                    "isHomeCompetitor": 0,
                    "teamId": 88261,
                    "teamName": "Singapore Slingers",
                    "teamGsId": null,
                    "teamNameInternational": "",
                    "teamNickname": "Singapore Slingers",
                    "teamNicknameInternational": "",
                    "teamCode": "",
                    "teamCodeInternational": "",
                    "website": "",
                    "internationalReference": "",
                    "externalId": "74",
                    "images": {
                        "logo": {
                            "L1": {
                                "size": "L1",
                                "height": 600,
                                "width": 600,
                                "bytes": 45196,
                                "url": "http://img.wh.sportingpulseinternational.com/5b71cf0a1af51c8376eda43e6ba5bc22L1.jpg"
                            },
                            "M1": {
                                "size": "M1",
                                "height": 400,
                                "width": 400,
                                "bytes": 25005,
                                "url": "http://img.wh.sportingpulseinternational.com/5b71cf0a1af51c8376eda43e6ba5bc22M1.jpg"
                            },
                            "S1": {
                                "size": "S1",
                                "height": 200,
                                "width": 200,
                                "bytes": 9180,
                                "url": "http://img.wh.sportingpulseinternational.com/5b71cf0a1af51c8376eda43e6ba5bc22S1.jpg"
                            },
                            "T1": {
                                "size": "T1",
                                "height": 75,
                                "width": 75,
                                "bytes": 2270,
                                "url": "http://img.wh.sportingpulseinternational.com/5b71cf0a1af51c8376eda43e6ba5bc22T1.jpg"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "clubId": 62,
                    "clubGsId": null,
                    "clubName": "Singapore Slingers",
                    "clubNameInternational": "",
                    "linkDetailClub": "/v1/basketball/clubs/62"
                },
```

Below is my loadUser function

```
   loadUser(){
this.http.get('http://api.wh.geniussports.com/v1/basketball/competitions/19816/matcheslive?ak=eebd8ae256142ac3fd24bd2003d28782')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.data = data.results;
      console.log(data.results);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

}

My main goal is to log the data[] array. Please help me

Comment: Your json format dont have any problem. If you are using ASP.NET as server, add cross-platform permission to your webconfig and router.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with browser, typically its a security concern not to allow other requests which may lead to XSS attack easily. If only for development I suggest you to install a [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en) which will disable in your browser plugin

If for production, then you need to configure your API then do [this](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/) .